# My old question needs another attention

Tags: support, openid

I want to re-edit my question so that it will come in latest questions again and you all experts can look and help me. 
But i forgot my actual login id i used to post for the question.

This is the link to my actual question.
[My actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854989/dsnless-connection-for-aruna-db/3370865#3370865)

I deeply apologize for my action here if it is a violation of SO community ethics.

Comment: Why don't you just use the "I forgot my login information" on the login page and have the old id sent to your email?

Answer (score 1):

No worries, we're glad to see you care about your question.

Did you insert your email address when you created that account? If so, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

As pointed out by George in the actual question, you can also have a moderator merge your new account with the old one, so you can access all old data again.

And finally, you can also drop a message to the SO team by email and explain your situation. I'm sure they'll find a way to help you.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You [are a registered user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309131/vijay), do you remember if you used OpenID or made an account directly?

If OpenID, Flag your question for moderator and ask them to e-mail you the OpenID URL associated with your account, if you provided your e-mail when filling out your profile. That should jog your memory enough to login. You may need to do password recovery with the OpenID provider if you can't remember it.

If that doesn't work, e-mail ***team@stackoverflow.com***